# How can I segregate the application jar and dependencies?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, build, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I've a spring-boot application with maven, the final jar is of 96MB+ and I want to reduce that jar size by excluding dependencies jars from final jar and keeping them in one remote location and redirecting the dependencies location from final jar. By removing `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from pom.xml, I've generated the jar which of size 3MB+ but that is not able to run, giving error `no main manifest attribute, in target\abc.jar`. I understood that it's not executable. Please guide me how can I have the dependencies in a remote location and redirect it from application jar and how can I make the jar executable?

I tried segregating application jar and dependencies.
I'm expecting a separate executable application jar and dependencies.

Comment: Think about the dependencies you have defined and check if they are really needed... removing spring-boot-maven-plugin will not help nor is spring-boot-maven-plugin part of the final jar ... Check every dependency you have defined in your pom file if you really need it or not...that will result in reducing the jar size..

Comment: Don't it will be more trouble then it is worth as you will be reinventing the wheel. If you really want use something like the [Spring Boot Thin Launcher](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher) instead of hacking away yourself.

Comment: The real point is this: `I tried segregating application jar and dependencies. I'm expecting a separate executable application jar and dependencies.` (Which I hand't read carefully enought) that can be achieved by spring thing launcher (written by @M.Deinum) but that will of course not reduce the overall size... The layers in Spring Boot maven plugin can give already some steps into this (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.layers)

Comment: Why wouldn't it reduce the overall size? It will only create a jar with the application classes and upon startup will download them (or if you are using a machine that already has the `.m2/repository` directory use them from there by default.